# Coordinates of the altitude

Tags: analytic-geometry

Suppose we have points $P(1,3,2), Q(0,-1,1), R(2,1,0)$. Let's consider a triangle PQR. Let's draw line segment from $R$ which is orthogonal to the side $QP$. Suppose it intersects this line at the point $S$. How to find coordinates of the $S$?

Can anyone help with this problem please.

Comment: $S$ is midpoint of $QP$.

Comment: So the co-ordinates of $S$ are $(\frac1{2}, 1,\frac3{2})$

Comment: @HVxvejjw, why it should be a midpoint? General it may not be a mid point. Could you show your reasoning?

Comment: In an Isoceles triangle the altitude drawn from the vertex bisects the base.

Answer (score 0):

We can write the equation of the $PQ$ line, in particular for a point $S$ as $$S=P+t(P-Q)=(1,3,2)+t[(0,-1,1)-(1,3,2)]=(1,3,2)+t(-1,-4,-1)$$
Write now the condition that $SR$ is perpendicular to $PQ$ using the scalar product:
$$(R-S)\cdot(P-Q)=0$$
Plug in the values for $P$, $Q$, $R$, and $S$, and you get an equation for $t$. This is a simple linear equation. Solve it. Then take the answer and use it in the formula for $S$.